# When an analysis with random effects returns random effects with a perfect correlation, does this mean that it can only estimate one of them?

Tags: mixed-model, random-variable, random-effects-model

I have read the [recommendation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.04967.pdf) to perform dimension reduction on a random effects structure. I'm trying to get my head around exactly what this means. I assume it has to do with the fact that often a model will result in random effects that are perfectly correlated (i.e., redundant). Does this essentially mean that, say, a random slope and intercept give the exact same information (i.e., can be reduced to a single dimension) and so one of them can be removed?